# Regex to fetch whole and decimal numbers from paragrph

Tags: jquery, regex, decimal, paragraph, digits

I want to fetch the whole and decimal numbers from paragraph. I'm using jQuery and regular expression for this. here is my code:

```
jQuery("#Content_Text p, #Content_Text td").html(function (index, value) {
        value = value.replace(/(\s[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?(\s,\.,\,,\%)?)/, "<em style=\"color:#FF6600; font-size:12px; font-style: normal;\">$1</em>");
        return value;
    });
```

Matching & not matching examples:

1. has catapulted its position as the top 3 `<3 is matched>` countries
2. India stands 3rd `<3 is matched>` in the global housing index for 2012. `<2012. is not matched>`
3. *Economy and Realty, October 2012, Knight Frank. `<2012. is matched>`
4. India is in the range of 18.6% - 29% pa `<18.6 is matched> but 29% is not!`

Please help me, I want to match all these cases!.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to match 2012 in sentence 2 but not in sentence 3? What's the rule here? Only match first number?

Comment: Never mind, I think I got what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a class character instead of `(\s,\.,\,,\%)`

```
[\s.,%]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the /g flag on your regex to match more than just the first occurence. Also, this part of your regex is a bit odd:

```
(\s,\.,\,,\%)?
```

I suspect you don't actually need any of that. You made it optional anyway, so it won't matter. Also, there's a redundant digit matching in the beginning. Try this:

```
value.replace(/\s(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g, "<em style=\"color:#FF6600; font-size:12px; font-style: normal;\">$1</em>")
```

Note that you're requiring an empty space, \s, in front of the number. That won't match in the beginning of sentences. Try replacing it with a word boundary, \b, if that's what you want.

Comment: `value.replace(/\s(\d+(\.\d+)?)/gi` working fine for me. Thanks dude. one more thing, can u please suggest me what if I need match the (%) symbol? i.e. 27.78%